# How to calculate winning chances of one poker hand against another?

Tags: algorithms

My question relates to [Texas Hold'em Poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_hold_%27em). But I believe it will be the same algorithm for any kind of poker game.

So let's consider two hands: `AJo` and `KQo`. I can use [online calculator](http://www.cardplayer.com/poker-tools/odds-calculator/texas-holdem) and find out that `AJo` wins in 59.48% cases.

My question is: how can I calculate this probability programmatically?

Of course I can use brute force but it's very inefficient way. Above two hands have `48 * 47 * 46 * 45 * 44 = 205.5 millions` combinations.

Does anybody know more efficient way to calculate that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about the math than the programming.

Comment: Take a look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12279/Fast-Texas-Holdem-Hand-Evaluation-and-Analysis. I had the same curiosity a little while ago and found this library really helpful.

Comment: @Blrfl He'd probably be better off at the [poker](http://poker.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: You're not interested in all possible combinations. There are only 2.5 million ordered five card combinations. If you consider five card combinations of equal value as one "hand", then there are only 7000 distinct hands in five card poker and only about 5000 distinct hands in Texas hold'em. [Read this Wikipedia-article about poker hands.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands)

Comment: @Blrfl: algorithm design questions are clearly on-topic here. They are not off-topic just because there is some mathematics involved. See [this meta post](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6663/can-i-ask-this-question-about-the-effectiveness-of-a-mathematical-programming-co) about a similar question, for example.

Comment: Algorithm questions are on-topic.

Comment: Although there are a lot of combinations you only have to calculate it once and put the answer in a database

Answer (score 5):

Only about 1.7 million combinations. The same five cards can appear in 120 different orders, so divide your number by 120. It doesn't take long to calculate a winner for those 1.7 million combinations.

Comment: That's just for the board. There is then the donkey work of finding (and ranking) sets of 5 cards from the 7 card power set.

Comment: @RobbieDee It's possible to write the hand evaluation function so that it handles card sets of seven cards (instead of only five). I think that's faster than iterating the five card subsets of a seven card set and running the evaluation for each five card subset.

Comment: @COMEFROM Well, indeed - however you want to do it. Your approach would need adjusting for variants such as Omaha though...

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're describing is in a realm of mathematics called Combinatorics, or sometimes Discrete Mathematics, and is essential to the study of computer science.

To learn about this branch of mathematics in relation to your specific problem, I refer you to [this article](http://www.thepokerbank.com/strategy/mathematics/hand-combinations/) which explains it very thoroughly

Answer (score 2):

I recommend searching for the `XPokerEval` library. It doesn't contain trivial algorithms for this (a.k.a. brute-force ones), but it contains various efficient evaluation algorithms implemented mainly in C, C# and Java. You can then look at how they're implemented.

It involves a fair amount of bitwise operations, so it's going to take a while to understand them.

The original blog-post which described and introduced this library is no longer accessible, but you can still find multiple copies of its code on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it would take a shorter time to do the very complex calculations of the probability of each hand winning, than it will to run through all possible combination of the board and determine in each case which hand wins.

But to create a program that determines which calculations to do based on the two hands will take far longer than to create a program that just runs through all possible combinations.

If you want a program that can give you an answer today, brute force it. If you want a program that can give a very quick answer, you'll have it done somewhere around 2037.

Just to try to paint a picture of how complex the calculations actually are, `AJs` wins when `KQo` does not improve, unless the board is then the winning hand in which case it is a tie. If `KQo` improves then it wins, unless `AJs` also improves at least as much, again unless the board is the winning hand.

Comment: 1.7 million is not a large number. A bad brute-force program might take a couple of minutes. A good brute-force program would probably run in a few seconds.

Comment: @kevincline I can confirm your estimate. I've written a simple Hold'em calculator with Java to count the exact Hold'em probabilities and also to provide estimates while going. Without any special optimization the program could provide the exact final result within few seconds from any reasonable game state, on a year 2000 or so desktop computer. I bet the program would run a lot faster on a current machine and Java VM.

Answer (score 1):

Poker math is a specialist field. You don't give a great deal of info in your post but I'm going to assume heads up, no betting and cards dealt to the river (5th street if you prefer).

Odds calculators such as *Poker Cruncher* allow you to set the hand up and then they deal thousands of hands and see which one holds up.

For a usable tool, it isn't really practical (or that useful) to calculate each and every board. Yes, there will be (and is) variance each time the numbers are crunched but as long as a decent number of sample boards have been dealt, they're pretty accurate (well, accurate enough to make a better decision than you otherwise would have). N.B. Poker Cruncher comes out at 59.5% for the win in infinite mode.

If you're planning on using this for actual play, this is a very blunt tool indeed. There are many other factors to consider: [EV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value), position, reads, blinds, stack, table image, steals etc etc etc.

Comment: It's totally practical to calculate each and every board.

Comment: @kevincline As an academic exercise in this isolated case - yes. In reality - no. Beyond heads up, such exhaustive calculations become unwieldy **very** quickly.

Comment: Not sure what the complication is, to be honest. Less than 2 million combinations on the board, 42 possible ways to pick the best five cards from each player's hand, 5 cards to sort in each making 20 comparisons using bubblesort, then 10 simple predicates that examine the suit and/or value of each sorted card in order. Memory usage is minimal, so should fit in cache, therefore we can work on processor cycles. Assuming about 10 cycles for each described operation, that's 700*42*2M cycles or substantially less than a second per calculation.

Comment: ... Plus the calculation can be short-circuited, and there are several obvious ways of avoiding a lot of the work. With a few days work, should you need it, it ought to be possible to bring this down to less than 0.1s. And I've ignored the possibility of instruction level parallelism, or even using multiple cores.

Comment: @Jules Then I'd suggest you try writing such software as I have. Also read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability_(Texas_hold_%27em)) or your Google-fu should be able to turn up other good articles. Most software of this ilk uses [Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) methods for very good reasons: you don't need to bother with exhaustive analysis, they are much faster and (near as damn it) the results are the same to within a fraction of a percentage. None of the pros I have worked with work beyond 2 decimal places.